# C# Contar la cantidad de 0 a nivel columna Matriz

Tags: c#, array, matriz

tengo un ejercicio en el que debo contar la cantidad de ceros a nivel columna de una matriz. Pensé que podría recorrerlo por columnas e ir sumando un contador de la siguiente manera, pero me da error:

```
static void ContarCeros(int[,] matriz)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                int cant = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(0); j++)
                {
                    
                    if (matriz[i,j] == 0 )
                    {
                        cant++;
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"Cantidad de CEROS en la columna {i + 1}: {cant}");
            }
        }
```

El error ocurre en la condición del if, en donde me dice que se excedió del rango del array.

Al recorrerlo por las filas (utilizando "matriz.GetLenght(0)" en el primer ciclo for) no me da error y cuenta los ceros, pero no es lo que necesito.

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: @gbianchi ahi edité el post, tal vez se entienda mejor. Gracias por la recomendación.

Comment: La definicion de filas y columnas es borrosa en una matriz.. la primera serian las filas, las segundas las columnas... i y j estan bien, pero los GetLength estan totalmente al reves.. por eso se te va....